# reverse crowd sale possibility

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

Is it possible to do a reverse crowd sale? e.g. send tokens to a smart contract to get ether back. Or would this require to load the contract with WETH or something in advance?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you already have a token and a regular smart contract which has been used for token distribution and you now want to write a new contract for reverse distribution.

A small problem is that a contract can't detect when someone sends it tokens (and anyway contracts can't execute anything by themselves - only through a transaction). But what you *can* do it write a contract which handles the token transfer by itself - the token owner just needs to approve token withdrawal in advance. So it could work something like this:

1) Token owner issues a `approve` transaction to the token contract and names your reverse contract as the spender.

2) Token owner issues a separate transaction to your reverse contract which performs the transfer with `transferFrom`

3) If the token transfer (transferFrom) is successful the contract sends Ether to the (ex) token owner.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if you can create a crowd sale where the payment method is ERC20 tokens, and the distributed currency is Ether.

Comment: As I see it, yes, as I just tried to describe in my answer. If you didn't understand some part of the answer feel free to ask more about it.